# Ignore personal configuration files in git

Tags: git, azure, gitignore

I am working on a repository with other developers. 
Every developer has it's own Azure account for testing purposes, meaning every developer has a different connection string to use for local development. And for the production environment the setting is different either.

So we are using a Web.config with several settings, which is checked in to git. But I don't want that any developer accidentally pushes his connection string, so I extracted it to a seperate file privateDevSettings.config.

Web.config:

```
<appSettings file="privateDevSettings.config">
    <add key="generalSetting" value="123" />
</appSettings>
```

privateDevSettings.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="azureConString" value="put your personal azure connection string here"/>
</appSettings>
```

My idea is that every developer sets their personal connection string in the privateDevSettings.config and by using gitignore for this file, nobody checks in their setting. But apparently, when ignoring this file, it also has to be removed from the repository. But I'd rather keep the file so each developer knows what to do.

Any solutions to this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1) Instead of using the existence of `privateDeevSettings.config` in the repo to document your procedure, you could put comments in `web.config` to tell the developer how to do his local configuration.  Then you could remove `privateDevSettings.config` from the repo and .gitignore it (or just arrange that it live outside the repo work tree)

2) Are you ultimately packaging this as a war?  If so, the war plugin can "filter" resources (interpolating values like connection strings at build time).  So instead of having a file you (mostly) want to ignore, you could let developers set their connection string via environment, or a properties file completely outside source control, or a number of other options.